# how to grab a hash from database tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, group-by

I'm trying to grab a hash of all my Events grouped by date so it has [y-m-d] => "event.title" or something like like.

Here are some things I've tried but don't seem to work:

```
@events = Event.all
@events_by_date = @events.group_by{ |e| e.created_at.beginning_of_month }
                                  #&:day)
                                  #&:created_at).day
                                  #&:edate)
                        #.group_by(&:group_by_criteria).map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}.sort
                        #.group("date_format(created_at, '%Y%m%d %H')").count
```

I've tried some stuff in the model like this:

```
def group_by_criteria
    created_at.to_date.to_s(:db)
end
def day
    where(created_at.strftime('%Y-%W-%D')
end
```

Can someone please help me learn how to get a hash from the database?

By the way, this works:  `events.group_by(&:created_at)`

But it says:[image]

and doesn't that group it by the Date AND TIME? I just want to group it all by the year, month day, excluding the rest of the timestamp.

Comment: It's much better to paste errors and results as plain text than a hard to read screenshot.

Comment: sorry, here's the important part: `{Mon, 06 Oct 2014 20:38:00 UTC +00:00=>[#<Event id:1,.....>]...}` the important part is that this key includes the TIME part of the DATETIME element. I'd like to exclude that TIME portion because I believe thats why my calendar isn't populated with my events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group events together by date, what you want is this:

```
Event.all.group_by(&:created_date)
```

Where that's a method you add to your Event model:

```
def created_date
  self.created_at.to_date
end
```

Remember `events` is a collection of Event models, it does not have a `created_at` method, only the individual elements of that collection do. The `group_by` method evaluates the method call per-element.